# Render javascript that stored in database

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, umbraco

I have in the database table just one column and it's content either javascript link like

```
<script src="some src"></script>
```

or javascript code like

```
<script>
some code
<script>
```

So my question is it possible to correct render that javascript inside cshtml file?

Comment: For the first, you'd need to actually have that `some src` file be available on your web server. For the second, have you tried anything?

Comment: @cricket_007 I tried direct include like this Model.JsContent. Model.JsContent contains actually javascript link

Comment: Can you please edit your question to include a [mcve]?

Comment: From what I've understood, you are trying to get a JavaScript code inside a <script> tag from your .csthml file. Am I right?

Comment: This sounds like an absolute security nightmare...

Comment: I try to make followring: 1. in controller action i set field of view model object to <script>alert('test');</script> and in chstml i try to render it like @Html.Raw(Model.JsContent). But I don't see alert.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Html.Raw` method in your view

```
@model YourViewModel
@Html.Raw(Model.YourScriptContent)
```

Assuming `YourScriptContent` is the property of your view model on which you are setting the script content value, in your  GET action.

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
   var vm = new YourViewModel();
   vm.YourScriptContent =  "<script>alert('testing');</script>";
   return View(vm);
}
```

By default, razor will HTML encode the return value of any c# code/expression with the prefix `@`. But the `Raw` method will return the markup which is not HTML encoded, which is what you need in this case.

Since you are not HTML encoding when you render it, I am hoping you completely trust the script content values :). Read about script injection attacks if you do not follow the previous statement.

Comment: What specifically is not working ? What is happening with this implementation ?

Comment: it is rendered as is, but not calls alert function

Comment: check your browser console. I guess your script content is invalid

Comment: I'm sorry i forget to mention that it is for umbraco crm

Comment: what is  the source of the generated page?